# Async inside querying mysql

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I have the following code:

```
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM scraper_accounts WHERE is_used = 0 LIMIT 1', function (error, results, fields) {
            
            scraper_accounts[used_index] = await login(
                                            {
                                                inputLogin: results[0].username,
                                                inputPassword: results[0].password,
                                                inputProxy: random_proxy.trim(),
                                            }

                                        )
            
           
        });
```

Why does it give me an error saying that it's missing a parentheses on the await login part?

Comment: First of all, the callback of `connection.query` is synchronous, you can't use `await ` there. Second, your condition in `while (random_proxy == null)` will always be false, because you initialize `random_proxy` with `"http://" + ...` which will never be `null`. Third: please post the exact error message

Comment: @derpirscher the random_proxy is irrelevant so i took that out of the question

Comment: If `login` is indeed an `async function` (nobody knows, because you don't show its definition), the code is fine and won't throw any errors about parenthesis. Still the callback isn't async, thus you can't use `await` at that position.